# Prevent Timer Until it ends - progress bar using Timer JAVA SWING

Tags: java, swing, timer, progress-bar

I have a progress bar that go to 100% using swing.Timer,
My problem is when I click a button so it will call the function that do the work,
Whenever I click it again the bar goes faster because am using counter.
I want the progress bar to go normal with no multiple incrementations.
Here is the code below and sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
final Timer t = new Timer(50, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1);
        if (jProgressBar1.getValue() == 100) {
          ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
}
```

Comment: Removed JavaFX tag as the question appears unrealated to JavaFX.

Comment: thanks i thought it was related.

Comment: *Whenever I click it again the bar goes faster* - that is because you start another Timer every time you click the button. Don't do this. The Timer should be created once.  Then the ActionEvent simply starts the Timer. Another option is to disable the button when it is clicked and then enable the button when the timer is stopped.

Comment: …and mind the beauty of local variables: `int newValue = jProgressBar1.getValue() + 1; jProgressBar1.setValue(newValue); if(newValue == 100) { ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop(); }` No need to ask the `jProgressBar1` for the value you already know (because you just set it).

Comment: @camickr i used this method ( disable enable after ) and it work fine but i want a clean and good way to do it  without disabling anything :c i tried Thread.sleep but it does not work me it just stop the whole program until it ends . thanks for your reply

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the advice <3

Comment: *i want a clean and good way to do it without disabling anything* - then I don't understand the question because that was my first suggestion on how to solve the problem.

Comment: @camickr mm i wanted when i click on a button the progress bar go to the 100% in the same speed because when i click another time without the progress ends it go faster and faster ... i hope you understand

Comment: And I already told you the solution. `Don't create and start a second Timer every time you click the button!` What is not clear about my first comment?

Comment: i got your answer and i found the solution according to your logic ... thanks a lot , the solution was very sample i don't know why i didn't figure it out already .